iOS How to test subscription purchased in production with iOS upladed to TestFlight
My QA team wants to test restore of the purchases done in production using the app I upload to TestFlight. Every time they try to restore purchases they get No Active subscriptions found. And on iPhone under Settings>User>Subscriptions there is a yearly subscription with a valid date.
I know that TestFlight app uses sandbox environment so it does not see production subscriptions. How can I enable them to test restoring of the subscription out before releasing the app to production?
